# How to check if field value is same as combobox value?

Tags: mysql, sql, vba, ms-access, combobox

So I am making a SQL query in which value of combobox (cboVU) shoud be same as field in table called Vrsta uredaja in table O klima uredaju. I am making this query in Access 2016.

I am getting this:

[image]

```
 strRowsource2 = "SELECT " & _
                 "  Vlasnik.ID_VU, " & _
                 "  Vlasnik.[Naziv tvrtke], " & _
                 "  Vlasnik.[Ime korisnika], " & _
                 "  Vlasnik.[Prezime korisnika], " & _
                 "  Vlasnik.[Adresa korisnika], " & _
                 "  Vlasnik.Telefon, " & _
                 "  Vlasnik.Mail, " & _
                 "  [O klima uredaju].[Vrsta uredaja], " & _
                 "  Narudzba.Datum " & _
                 "FROM Vlasnik " & _
                 "INNER JOIN ([O klima uredaju] " & _
                 "INNER JOIN Narudzba " & _
                 "  ON [O klima uredaju].ID_KU = Narudzba.ID_KU) " & _
                 "  ON Vlasnik.ID_VU = Narudzba.ID_VU WHERE ([O klima uredaju].[Vrsta uredaja] = " & cboVU & ")) "
       List1.RowSource = strRowsource2
```

Tables and relations:
[image]

Comment: The linked to image does not appear to be an error. It appears to only be a dialog box.

Comment: is the where comparison a text value as you'll need =" & """ & cboVU & """"

Comment: test your sql as a query

Comment: @Charles, it is not an error but an unwanted result.

Comment: Your join syntax looks dodgy.

Comment: It was made by Access, I didn't write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue on @Nathan_Sav's comment:

```
    Private Sub cboVU_Change()

    strRowsource2 = "SELECT " & _
                     "  Vlasnik.ID_VU, " & _
                     "  Vlasnik.[Naziv tvrtke], " & _
                     "  Vlasnik.[Ime korisnika], " & _
                     "  Vlasnik.[Prezime korisnika], " & _
                     "  Vlasnik.[Adresa korisnika], " & _
                     "  Vlasnik.Telefon, " & _
                     "  Vlasnik.Mail, " & _
                     "  [O klima uredaju].[Vrsta uredaja], " & _
                     "  Narudzba.Datum " & _
                     "FROM Vlasnik " & _
                     "INNER JOIN ([O klima uredaju] " & _
                     "INNER JOIN Narudzba " & _
                     "  ON [O klima uredaju].ID_KU = Narudzba.ID_KU) " & _
                     "  ON Vlasnik.ID_VU = Narudzba.ID_VU " & _
                     "WHERE [O klima uredaju].[Vrsta uredaja] = " & "'" & cboVU.Value & "'" & " "

Debug.Print strRowsource2
Debug.Print List1.RowSource

List1.RowSource = strRowsource2

End Sub
```